# jQuery plugin placeholder without using placeholder attribute

Tags: jquery-plugins, placeholder

I'm looking for a jQuery plugin placeholder that doesn't use placeholder attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fairly simple to build yourself — here's a quick example:

```
$.fn.placeholder = function(){
    return $(this).each(function(){
        $(this)
            .data('original-value', $(this).val())
            .focus(function(){
                var $input = $(this);
                if ($input.val() == $input.data('original-value'))
                    $input.val("");
            })
            .blur(function(){
                var $input = $(this);
                if ($.trim($input.val()) == "")
                    $input.val($input.data('original-value'));
            });
    });
};

$('input').placeholder();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrHjH/1